# Authentication Error: Compute instance for Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I created Compute instance in Azure Machine Learning in the Edge browser right after logging in. When it was started, I clicked on the Jupyter link.

I got the following authentication error: "User live.com#myname@outlook.com does not have access to compute instance vm-aml-lab4.
Only the creator can access a compute instance."

Is there a way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the AML compute instance only allows the creator to access the CI.It's known bug, once it's fixed we will update you. We think it is related to MSA accounts.

Comment: This seems a bit short for an accepted answer : I am facing the same problem right now but still have no clue to fix it... Could you provide a link to monitor the achievement status of the issue ?

Comment: Any update on this? I am having the same issue, and for me, it looks related to email mangling Azure does for some reason. The error message "User live.com#<MY_EMAIL_HERE> does not have access to compute instance workbench." hints that I should have live.com#MY_EMAIL_HERE user added in IAM, but, obviously, I have only MY_EMAIL_HERE user.

Comment: did they fixed it? am also getting the same error while accessing the compute instance using the service principal

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the exact same thing. I always have this issue when using Edge browser. I can **sometimes** avoid this by using Chrome after completely clearing all browsing history.